# Should I use highly skewed features in my model?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, skewness

Many of my features are highly skewed as you can see below in the figure. Should I be using such skewed data for modeling purposes?  If I cannot, then is there any way to integrate such features in my model?
[image: Highly Skewed Feature]
Since most of my features have a distribution plot like this, can I make a good machine learning model from such data?

Comment: How many distinct values? Exact zeros? Can you show a plot of its log (or maybe of $\log(x+1)$?

Answer (score 6):

Appropriate question.

The added value of preprocessing depends on the type of classifier you will train. If you use nonparametric classifiers like C4.5 (ID3), CART, the multinomial classifier, the webservice [insight classifiers](https://insight-classifiers.com/wos), random forests or the like - transformation of your skewed feature values is unnecessary. Their algorithms use histogram-like criteria to choose the optimal classifier parameters.

Classifiers like (deep) neural networks, discriminant analysis, support vector machines, logistic regression - they all use some sort of (local) distance measure. For such models a log-transformation or a power transformation (e.g. $\sqrt{x}$) are highly recommended for your use case.